# Using a char a[10]..but able to put only 5 values?

Tags: c, arrays

Using a char a[10]..but able to put only 5 values..and i also want output in string format in single line..i am using following code....

```
int main(){
char arr[10]={'\0'};
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  scanf("%c",&arr[i]);
       }
   printf("%s",arr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Arya Do you determine how the end of the string to it if I put the letter?

Comment: To help us write better answers in the future, please provide example input, and expected and actual output for that input. Also, if you haven't done so yet, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sory my mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `scanf` to read single characters, you have to remember that the newline you enter after each character is *also* a character. And so it will be read by the `scanf` calls as well. That means that only every other character you enter will be in the array, and every other character will be a newline. To solve this you have to tell `scanf` to skip whitespace, which is what the space character before the format in `" %c"` does.

And because you read ten characters, you don't terminate the string properly so printing the string will most likely lead to undefined behavior as the `printf` call tries to read beyond the limits of the array in search of the terminator. If you want to read ten characters, you need to make your array `11` characters long.

Comment: What if he enter `asdfghjkl` and then press Enter key?

Comment: @haccks That should obviously work, though my second paragraph is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

1) Add space at the beginning of the string format of `scanf()`

```
scanf(" %c",&arr[i]);
```

In your code, the white spaces (hiting ENTER (new line) or SPACE ...) is catched in the `scanf("%c",&arr[i]);` and you have to avoid the catch of the white spaces by adding space at the beginning of the string format of the scanf

2) And your for loop should be stop at 8 and not at 9

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
```

Otherwise you will not have a null terminator for your arr[] string and so you will get **undefined behaviour** and you can get garbage in the output of `printf()`

Comment: Are you sure placing an space before `%c` is of worth here?

Comment: haccks..buddy are u there??

Answer (score 1):

you are setting 5 numbers, but 10 values.

each number you put enter, adds 2 values to your array, the value you entered, and the "enter" key.
this is also the reason the numbers are not int he same line....
BTW, to see this, add some print inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you enter a character in first scanf then push enter key which is \n.In fact the second scanf is read \n. When you use %c, \n is a Effective character.

You can do like this.

```
int i;
char arr[11]={'\0'};
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    scanf("\n%c",&arr[i]);//Ignore the first \n
}
printf("%s",arr);
```